# Build a Primitive Root Diffuser

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, primes

#### Introduction

When a room has bare, parallel walls, it can create unpleasant repeating acoustic reflections (echoes).  A diffuser is a device mounted on a wall which creates a blocky surface of many different heights.  This has the effect of breaking up the reflected sound into many smaller reflections (each with a different time delay).  The acoustic quality of the room is thought to be greatly enhanced.

#### Primitive Root Diffuser

The primitive root diffuser uses a grid of (typically wooden) posts, each with a different height (to obtain a different reflection delay time).  The heights of the posts are chosen according to successive powers of a primitive root G, modulo N (a prime number).

[Here](https://www.gearslutz.com/board/bass-traps-acoustic-panels-foam-etc/428161-my-primitive-root-diffuser-build-check-out.html) are some pictures of a primitive root diffuser.

#### Task

You must write a program or function which takes a prime number N > 2 as its only input.  It must then select a primitive root of N.  G is a primitive root of N if the successive powers of G modulo N generate all the integers from 1 to N-1.  A more formal definition of primitive roots can be found in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n).

Your code must then place these successive powers into an X-by-Y array (or matrix).  Because we want to hang this on the wall, the diffuser should be a convenient shape - as close to square as possible.  The number of entries in the array will be N-1, so its dimensions X and Y should be chosen such that X*Y = N-1, and X is near but not equal to Y (specifically, X and Y are coprime).  For convenience of display, the horizontal dimension should be greater than the vertical dimension.

The order of placement of successive powers of G (modulo N) should start at one corner of the array, then traverse diagonally through the array, wrapping around in both directions until all array positions are filled.  Then the function should return that array, or print it to stdout, whichever you prefer.

We won't concern ourselves with the measurement units used to actually cut the posts to length; we'll assume the units are appropriate for the range of audio frequencies we want to diffuse, and stick to integers.

There's an [online calculator](http://www.oliverprime.com/prd/), in case you want to check your work.  However, the site appears to be down currently.

#### Example

Suppose we choose N = 41.  Our program should select one of the primitive roots of N, which are [6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 22, 24, 26, 28, 29, 30, 34, 35].  Suppose our program selects the smallest primitive root, G = 6.

Our program then chooses the squarest dimensions X,Y for the array such that X*Y = N-1.  The clear choice is X=8 and Y=5.

Then our program populates the array with successive powers of G modulo N (starting with G^0), traversing diagonally.  The program then returns/prints the array:

```
1   14  32  38  40  27  9   3
18  6   2   28  23  35  39  13
37  26  36  12  4   15  5   29
10  17  33  11  31  24  8   30
16  19  20  34  25  22  21  7
```

Note how it begins with 6^0 mod 41 = 1, then 6^1 mod 41 = 6, then 6^2 mod 41 = 36, then 6^3 mod 41 = 11, etc.

To clarify, the sequence of powers of 6 modulo 41 is:

```
[1, 6, 36, 11, 25, 27, 39, 29, 10, 19, 32, 28, 4, 24, 21, 3, 18, 26, 33, 34, 40, 35, 5, 30, 16, 14, 2, 12, 31, 22, 9, 13, 37, 17, 20, 38, 23, 15, 8, 7]
```

#### Another Example

N = 31

Assuming the program selects G = 11, X = 6, Y = 5, the output is:

```
1   26  25  30  5   6
4   11  7   27  20  24
16  13  28  15  18  3
2   21  19  29  10  12
8   22  14  23  9   17
```

#### A Third Example

N = 37

Assuming the program selects G = 2, X = 9, Y = 4, the output is:

```
1   12  33  26  16  7   10  9   34
31  2   24  29  15  32  14  20  18
36  25  4   11  21  30  27  28  3
6   35  13  8   22  5   23  17  19
```

#### Scoring

Standard code golf rules - the fewest bytes of code producing correct output wins!

Comment: if I choose to write a function, can I return the string or should I print it? are there specific requirements for spacing between numbers?

Comment: How do you continue if you hit [0,0] before you cover all tiles? Please provide an example for N=37

Comment: @proud haskeller:  No spacing requiremnts, returning or printing are both fine.

Comment: @PeterTaylor but for example on 17 the grid is 4x4 which means you loop on the diagonal but never give a number for the rest of the tiles

Comment: @phosgene did you mean returning the actual matrix instead of a string of the matrix? is that okay?

Comment: @proud haskeller:  Sure, any output format is acceptable.  It can have brackets, commas, tabs, or whatever.

Comment: I edited the question to specify that X and Y should be as close as possible, while still being coprime.  That eliminates the problems with a 4x4 array for N=17, or a 6x6 array for N=37,

Comment: @phosgene but it opens a new problem where N=17 produces a 1x16 "square" :-(

Comment: @JanDvorak:  True, but it's unavoidable for this diagonal traverse method.  Even traversing the array normally, you still run into problems with N=47, for example, with a 23-by-2 array as the best choice.  Some primes are better than others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Mathematica 158

Spaces not needed:

```
f@n_ := (m = Mod;
        {p, q} = Sort[{y-x, x, y} /. Solve[x*y==n - 1 && x~GCD~y == 1 < x < y, Integers]][[1, 2 ;;]];
        (g[#~m~p + 1, #~m~q + 1] = m[PrimitiveRoot@n^#, n]) & /@ (Range@n - 1);
         g~ Array~{p, q})
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The last one looks like this ...

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm definitely going to steal these infix tricks!

Comment: @phosgene You're welcome:)

Comment: Teaching Haskell a thing or two about lazy golfing, I see  :D

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yup. Thanks. Also, I'm quite sure the factorization can be done better. I tried the minimization functions with inconsistent results

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>220</s> <s>213</s> <s>207</s> <s>201</s> <s>194</s> <s>182</s> 178

```
f n=[map(x%)[0..j-1]|x<-[0..i-1]]where j=[x|x<-l,x^2>n,(n-1)&x<1,gcd(n`div`x)x<2]!!0;i=n`div`j;0%0=1;a%b=([x|x<-l,all((>1).(&n).(x^))l]!!0*(a-1)&i%((b-1)&j))&n;l=[1..n-2]
(&)=mod
```

this is a function which returns a matrix (a list of lists of `Int`).

it works by calculating the smallest possible `g`, the closet coprime `j` and `k` and defines a recursive function that given the indices of a slot in the grid returns the Integer in it, and maps this function over all slots.

**example output:**

```
*Main> mapM_ print $ f 13 -- used for printing the matrix line-by-lie
[1,5,12,8]
[3,2,10,11]
[9,6,4,7]

*Main> mapM_ print $ f 43
[1,21,11,16,35,4,41]
[37,3,20,33,5,19,12]
[36,25,9,17,13,15,14]
[42,22,32,27,8,39,2]
[6,40,23,10,38,24,31]
[7,18,34,26,30,28,29]

*Main> mapM_ print $ f 37
[1,12,33,26,16,7,10,9,34]
[31,2,24,29,15,32,14,20,18]
[36,25,4,11,21,30,27,28,3]
[6,35,13,8,22,5,23,17,19]
```

Comment: It's like hitting a golf ball with a category theory textbook!

Comment: Nice use of list comprehension, maybe it's a good idea to add to the Haskell golfing tips if it's not already there.

Comment: @TheSpanishInquisition Yes, actually

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2: <strike>232 217 212 208 201 198 194 192</strike> 187 bytes

```
N=input()
w=n=G=N-1
Z=range(n)
while sorted(G**x%N-1for x in Z)!=Z:G-=1
while w*w/n|n%w|1-all(w%i|n/w%i for i in Z[2:]):w-=1
n/=w
a=[]
for x in Z:a+=[n*[0]];a[x%w][x%n]=G**x%N
print a[:w]
```

Now it selects the largest root instead of the smallest, so output is different.
Example:

```
41
[[1, 27L, 32L, 3L, 40L, 14, 9L, 38L], [18L, 35, 2L, 13L, 23L, 6L, 39, 28L], [37L, 15L, 36, 29L, 4L, 26L, 5L, 12L], [10L, 24L, 33L, 30, 31L, 17L, 8L, 11L], [16L, 22L, 20L, 7L, 25, 19L, 21L, 34L]]
```

Comment: Looks like a close race so far!

Comment: `a+=[n*[0]];` -> `a+=n*[0],;`.

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB w/ Symbolic Toolbox - <s>199</s> 198 bytes

Minified:

```
function C=F(N),M=N-1;y=1:N;p=y-1;t=@(x)eval(mod(sym(x).^p,N));l=M./y;L=fix(l);k=y(l==L.*gcd(y,L)&y>M^.5);k=k(1);l=M/k;C=eye(l,k);g=y(arrayfun(@(x)sum(t(x)<2)<3,y));C(mod(p,k)*l+mod(p,l)+1)=t(g(1));
```

Expanded:

```
function C = primroot( N )

M = N-1;
y = 1:N;
p = y-1;
t = @(x) eval( mod( sym(x).^p, N ) );
l = M./y;
L = fix( l );
k = y( l == L.*gcd(y,L) & y > M^.5 );
k = k(1);
l = M/k;
C = eye( l, k );
g = y(arrayfun( @(x) sum( t(x) < 2 ) < 3, y ));
C(mod(p,k)*l+mod(p,l)+1) = t(g(1));
```

#### Sample Outputs

```
primroot(37)

ans =

 1    12    33    26    16     7    10     9    34
31     2    24    29    15    32    14    20    18
36    25     4    11    21    30    27    28     3
 6    35    13     8    22     5    23    17    19

primroot(41)

ans =

 1    14    32    38    40    27     9     3
18     6     2    28    23    35    39    13
37    26    36    12     4    15     5    29
10    17    33    11    31    24     8    30
16    19    20    34    25    22    21     7

primroot(31)

ans =

 1     6     5    30    25    26
16     3    18    15    28    13
 8    17     9    23    14    22
 4    24    20    27     7    11
 2    12    10    29    19    21

primroot(113)

ans =

  1    48    44    78    15    42    95    40   112    65    69    35    98    71    18    73
106     3    31    19     8    45    13    59     7   110    82    94   105    68   100    54
 49    92     9    93    57    24    22    39    64    21   104    20    56    89    91    74
109    34    50    27    53    58    72    66     4    79    63    86    60    55    41    47
 28   101   102    37    81    46    61   103    85    12    11    76    32    67    52    10
 30    84    77    80   111    17    25    70    83    29    36    33     2    96    88    43
 16    90    26     5    14   107    51    75    97    23    87   108    99     6    62    38
```

A noble effort for MATLAB (even if I do say so myself), the language that requires `a1 = b(c); a = a1(d);` because it doesn't understand `a = b(c)(d)`. :P

A few notes:

- the routine exploits the fact that `mod( j^k, N )` for `k = 0..N-1` is strictly positive for positive `j`, and that `j` is only a primitive root of `N` if the number `1` appears exactly twice in the sequence
- the routine exploits the fact that a number `x >= 2` can only equal `floor(x)*gcd(floor(x),y)` for positive `y` if `floor(x) == x` and `gcd(floor(x),y) == 1`. Also, the fact that `x` and `y` are coprime iff `gcd(x,y) == 1`.

Other than that, I couldn't find any problem-specific optimizations.

MATLAB's `mod` function is particularly painful since I use it 3 times, and it takes a minimum of 8 characters per invocation, as opposed to 3 (i.e. `x%y`) for virtually every other programming language in existence. The `arrayfun` (which in every other language is either `map` or `->` is also painful.

In light of these handicaps, I also present the following solution:

#### Fantasy MATLAB - far fewer bytes

```
C = @(N):
M = N-1;
y = 1:N;
p = y-1;
t = @(x) eval( sym(x).^p % N );
L = fix( l = M./y );
k = y( l == L.*gcd(y,L) & y > M^.5 )(1);
C = ones( l = M/k, k );
C( p%k*l + p%l + 1 ) = t(y( x -> sum( t(x) < 2 ) < 3 )(1));
```

Comment: I admit I didn't expect to see MATLAB here.  It seems to golf pretty well for this problem!

Comment: @phosgene: I needed compact variable-precision arithmetic, reasonable matrix handling, and a `gcd` or `coprime` function. This rules out C, C++, C#, Java, Javascript, Perl, and Maple, which are the only other standard languages I've coded in long enough to golf. I'm dabbling in CJam, since it's a golfing language. Personally I don't care for the "golf" aspect of challenges. I greatly prefer other criteria for winning. But easily 80% of the challenges on PPCG are golf-related, and beggars can't be choosers. ;)

Comment: It's hard to come up with a good win conditions that don't boil down to letting a program brute force a problem for hours.  If I think of any good problems, I'll be sure to post them.

Comment: @phosgene: I know exactly what you mean.

Comment: With regards to `a1 = b(c); a = a1(d);`... what's wrong with `a = b(c, d)` ?

Comment: Errors for N = 2. I am definitely learning something from this function declaration though...

Comment: @feersum: It works fine if `b` is a matrix. If `b` is a function returning a value, not so much. Regarding the `N = 2` case, it's both conceptually invalid (a diffuser with a single post wouldn't be a diffuser) and violates the spec ("X is near but not equal to Y"). The only possible dimensions for `N = 2` are `X = Y = 1`, meaning the spec is impossible to satisfy for `N = 2`.

Comment: True, the spec does say "X not equal to Y" at one point. It seems to be a bit self-contradictory. I was going by the requirement of them being coprime.

Comment: I fixed the problem definition to exclude N=2.  It causes nothing but trouble.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 84 bytes

```apl
{{⍵@(b∘|¨2⌿¨⍳≢⍵)⊢(b←{a⊃⍨⊃⍋+/↑a←(≠/¨⌿⊢)⍸⍵=∘.×⍨⍳⍵}≢⍵)⍴0}⊃(⍵∘{1=≢⍵~⍨⍳⍺}¨⌿⊢)↓⍵|∘.*⍨⍳⍵-1}
```

[Try it on repl.it!](https://repl.it/join/imysopnc-razetime)

Uses `⎕IO←0` (0-indexing).

A dfn which takes input as a long integer, and returns a matrix of long ints for the first primitive root of `⍵`.

Hosted on repl.it since tio is not updated with the latest version of dzaima/APL. The run button runs all testcases.

### Explanation

`{{⍵@(b∘|¨2⌿¨⍳≢⍵)⊢(b←{a⊃⍨⊃⍋+/↑a←(≠/¨⌿⊢)⍸⍵=∘.×⍨⍳⍵}≢⍵)⍴0}⊃(⍵∘{1=≢⍵~⍨⍳⍺}¨⌿⊢)↓⍵|∘.*⍨⍳⍵-1}`

`∘.*⍨⍳⍵-1` create a power table for 0..n-1

`⍵|`  modulo that by the input `⍵`

`↓` convert to list of lists

`(⍵∘{...}¨⌿⊢)` tacit function, filter lists where:

`1=≢⍵~⍨⍳⍺` numbers from 1 to n-1 are present

`⊃` take the first one

`{⍵@(b∘|¨2⌿¨⍳≢⍵)⊢(b←{a⊃⍨⊃⍋+/↑a←(≠/¨⌿⊢)⍸⍵=∘.×⍨⍳⍵}≢⍵)⍴0}` and do the following:

**Dimension finding function(courtesy of ngn):**

`{a⊃⍨⊃⍋+/↑a←(≠/¨⌿⊢)⍸⍵=∘.×⍨⍳⍵}≢⍵` do the following with the length of the first list:

`∘.×⍨⍳⍵` multiplication table of 1..length

`⍸⍵=` coordinates at which product = length

`(≠/¨⌿⊢)` remove the ones which create squares

`a←` assign the final coordinates to `a`

`⊃⍋+/↑` index of coordinate with highest sum

`a⊃⍨` take that coordinate from `a`

`b←` assign that to b

`(...)⍴0` create a grid of zeroes of that size

`⍵@(...)⊢` assign the first list at the following indices:

`⍳≢⍵` 1..length

`2⌿¨` each replicated twice

`b∘|¨` mod b(vectorizes)

This gives the final diagonally oriented matrix.